# control curves with bones

Tags: animation, bones, bezier-curves

Is there a way to control curves with bones? I already know the AnimAll addon and the Hook modifier, but I'd like to have IK-FK control on some 2D curves objects.

Comment: Please include an image to help your explanation.  IK-FK terminology is used for bones, so how does it apply to curves?.  What is lacking with the Hook Modifier using an armature bone?

Answer (score 3):

1. For each curve control point create a bone (separate not parented) and hook those vertexes to bones.
2. Now you can totally control the curve with armature.
3. Next you want to connect the bones with *Child_Ofs* constraints to link them into a chain.
4. When the *Child_Ofs* influences are at 1.0 you have FK control, when they are at 0.0 you have IK control (this setup is called FIK - forward inverse kinematic).
5. You can drive the influences with custom properties so it is accessible from the *Properties panel*.

Comment: I think it's more practical to hook selected curve points to empties using hook modifiers, then parent the empties to bones in a single armature (rather than multiple armatures) this way you will have better organized actions under a single armature umbrella.

Comment: @AhmedAli there is no need to have multiple armatures. Hooking different vertices to different bones inside single armature works. The empties are over-complication.

Comment: you're totally right, I guess I had misinterpreted your answer :)

Comment: How do I do the actual hooking to the bone? When I am in edit mode and I hit Ctrl + H for the Hook Menu, I can select the entry "Hook to selected Object: Bone" but whenever I do, I get the error "Cannot add Hook with no other selected Objects"

Comment: Ok, I found one way to do it: with the Outliner Panel:
1) You click on the Icon of the Bone you want to hook your curve point to, 
2) Shift-Click the Icon of your Bezier Curve Mesh Data Block. This will put you into Edit Mode on the Curve, the Bone will still be selected. You will be able to tell by the coloring of the Selection Border. Hook to Bone will now work. 

I tried this by manually adding Hook Modifiers to selected Curve points. That did NOT work. I don't know why, the modifiers look identical.