# Can an armature be added to a curve?

Tags: armature

I've got a tentacle, made from a cube with an array modifier (fit curve modifier) and a curve modifier:

[image]

I'd like to add an armature to the tentacle and incorporate it into a character.

Is it possible to add an armature to my current setup, without applying all of the modifiers?

Comment: You could use hooks http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/how-to-animate-a-curve-segment/21234#21234

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36845/control-curves-with-bones/36848#36848

Answer (score 2):

Consider using

- The Spline IK Modifier.
- Vertex hooks, where the hooks are bones of an armature.